# Recursive vbs function to save the files of a certain name without deleting the old ones

Tags: recursion, vbscript

Please, I search a recursive vbs function which takes a file name as input and checks if this one exists into a folder before save it on the file system. If it already exists into the folder then we must increment the old name. My goal is to keep the similar old file names by incrementing cleverly the next file names which are similar.

For exemple, inside a "D:\test" folder, It may already exist a file name called "incFile.txt". To save it inside "D:\test", we must first of all check if this one doesn't exist yet into the folder; If it already exists Then we must increment the old name as "incFile-1.txt" and so on.

Please see there what I have done, hoping that won't bother you. If you want to help me fix my errors, You can copy and run it right away on your computer since you have all the information.

```
dim readparam,mySavingName,concatene      'global variable

Set fso= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objF=fso.opentextfile("fileList.txt",1)
Do Until objF.AtEndOfStream
readparam = objF.readline
saveStrategy readparam
Loop

Sub saveStrategy(aFileName)

dim xmlDoc,objDoc

mySavingName=aFileName
mySavingName=recursion(mySavingName)
concatene="GAME-"&mySavingName

Set xmlDoc=createObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set oCreation = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
xmlDoc.insertBefore oCreation, xmlDoc.childNodes.Item(0)
Set objDoc = xmlDoc.createElement("Racine")
xmlDoc.appendChild(objDoc)

Set obj = _
xmlDoc.createElement("GAME-PLAY") 
obj.Text=aFile
objDoc.appendChild obj

xmlDoc.save(concatene)

'delete object after processing here on each line read from fileList.txt
Set xmlDoc=Nothing
Set oCreation=Nothing
Set objDoc=Nothing
end Sub

function recursion(mySavingName)
dim shift
shift=0
concatene="GAME-"&mySavingName
if fso.FileExists(concatene) Then
shift=shift+1
mySavingName=mySavingName&shift
nextSavingName=recursion(mySavingName)
Else
nextSavingName=mySavingName
End If
recursion=nextSavingName
end function

fileList.txt  'The inputs are the file names (inside the same folder as the .vbs program file)
konan
batman
casper
batman

Output Expected
GAME-konan
GAME-batman
GAME-casper
GAME-batman-1

Output Get with my code
GAME-
```

I run this program with no errors from prompt command. But result of my program is different from the expected result. Please If you have any question, don't hesitate and many thanks in advance for your attention and help.

Comment: SO is not a "write code for me free" type of site. Please show what you have tried and describe what you expected the code to do and how the results were different from what you expected.

Comment: Sorry, I had write some stuff. The reason for which I have not copied that is the fact that for a best understanding of my issue, I couldn't only copy my recursion function that I have written, but I would have had to copy all what I have done. Please see above update with what I have done, hoping that won't bother you. If you want to help me fix my errors, You can copy and run it right away on your computer since you have all the information. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have seen my error. I have replaced conditional structure

```
Do Until objF.AtEndOfStream
  readparam = objF.readline
  saveStrategy readparam
  Loop
```

with

```
Do While Not objF.AtEndOfStream
readparam = objF.readline
saveStrategy readparam
Loop
```

It works fine now!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your recursive function will work as you expect, because it keeps appending "1" to the string instead of incrementing the number, i.e. it will generate `GAME-xxx1`, then `GAME-xxx11`, then `GAME-xxx111` and so on. Also, iteration is a lot easier than recursion, so I'd implement the check like this:

```
...
concatene = GetSavingName("GAME-" & aFileName)
...

Function GetSavingName(mySavingName)
  savingName = mySavingName
  i = 0
  Do While fso.FileExists(savingName)
    i = i + 1
    savingName = mySavingName & i
  Loop
  GetSavingName = savingName
End Function
```